# Voltage doubler 0.7V to 1.4V DC output from air flow sensor

Tags: voltage, sensor

I need to double the DC output of an airflow sensor from 0.7V DC to 1.4V DC. There seem to be numerous options, which just confuse me, and I thought I would ask to see what you would recommend. 12V DC available.

Comment: Insufficient information. What is the voltage range of the airflow sensor? This is an automotive MAF sensor? Any link to data?

Comment: It's not much of a sensor if it outputs a steady 0.7v, presumably it outputs a _range_ of voltages? Is it a powered sensor or is it resistive and sensed by a voltage coming from the ECU?

Answer (score 2):

If the input signal is 0.7 volts DC and you want 1.4 volts DC then I'd consider using an op-amp circuit. It can be powered from 12V. You'd need a non-inverting gain of 2 configuration like this: -

[image]

Rf and Rg would typically be in the order of 1kohm to 100kohm (both the same value). The op-amp needs to connect to the 12V power rail and ground. You need to choose an op-amp whose input lines can work close to the ground. The LM324 sounds an obvious choice. It's a quad package op-amp but there are plenty of single op-amp versions aka LM321. Also don't forget to put 100nF across the supply pins to the chip.